# How to explicitly allow additional fields when using stripUnknown in Yup?

Tags: yup

I have generic framework code that validates incoming requests using Yup with `stripUnknown: true` so that excess fields are removed.  However, I have one place where I *explicitly* want to allow any JSON object as input.

How can I explicitly allow one object within a schema to have any fields while otherwise using `stripUnknown: true`?

Things I've considered but haven't figured out how to implement:

- Use `yup.object().test(...)` or similar to explicitly allow the object
- Use `yup.addMethod` to add a method to `yup.object()` which would short-circuit the stripping
- Use `yup.lazy` to generate a schema which allows anything (but the type should allow nested JSON, not only top-level fields)
- Add a new top-level type `yup.anyObject()` which would allow any object

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-playground-forked-4wksu?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing (and keeping) any value is actually as simple as:

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  json: yup.mixed()
});
```

This allows any value, not just an object.  If you want to validate that `json` is an object containing anything, you can use `yup.lazy` to map it into a schema having `yup.mixed()` for every key existing in the object:

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  json: yup.lazy((value) =>
    yup
      .object()
      .shape(
        Object.keys(value).reduce(
          (map, key) => ({ ...map, [key]: yup.mixed() }),
          {}
        )
      )
  )
});
```